# textarea changes font-size according to the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea

I don't know what happens in a desktop browser but in Android default browser when i keep the width and height as 100%
The font size of the textarea increases according to the screen I tried to alert the font - size of the textarea but it doesn't change .I think this is a bug in the browser  if not is there a way to fix this issue ?

Any help would be appreciated.

The code is simple it is:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<style>
  textarea{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   font-size:16px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  alert($("textarea").css("font-size"));//uses jquery
  //Outputs 16
</script>
```

I have noticed that the font size starts changing after the width becomes more than ~450px

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Disable zoom.

Comment: According to the accessibility guide lines we are not to disable zoom, this is unfriendly to the sight impaired.

Comment: I want to do this but I really don't want to be adjusted to viewport for the moment although adjusting to the viewport does solve the problem because the screen width becomes less than 450px :(

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem related to :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

simply check `<head>` tag and remove that if exist *--not Recommended --*

- another reason maybe related to `css` [media Query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
  check the media queries in `stylesheet` and change the `font-size`